# Strange error message when using IMPORTRANGE function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this strange message when I use this IMPORTRANGE function from a sheet:

*"Make sure you have access to the sheet you're trying to import from."*

The function is this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx"; "DB DEFINITVO!A2:Y8000")
```

The function has always worked, from 1 year till today, now it unexpectedly returns me this error. What is it due to?

Comment: Given the information you've provided, it looks like you do not own the source sheet, and that the owner has either rescinded your permission or changed the global permission on the source sheet such that you no longer have access. If you feel that is in error, your only recourse is to contact the owner and ask to have editor permission granted to you again.

Comment: I am the owner of both the sheets...

Comment: when you write the importrange function after entering it shows as red corner on the cell you just need to click that red corner and click allow access to grant access to the sheet.